# System.Reflection Usage

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a class

```
class ABC
{
    Public int one = 10;
    Public String two = "123";
  public override string ToString()
   {
   }
}
```

My question i want to get fields information/values in String of Class "ABC" when ever i will create an object of that class. For example:

```
Public Class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        ABC a = new ABC();
        a.ToString();
    }
}
```

Now here I create an object a of class "ABC", then i want to override method of ToString() to get all fields values of class ABC in a string.

**As solution this worked for me :**

```
**Here is an other solution if we use static fields and fieldsInfo:** 

class ReflectionTest
{
    public static int Height = 2;
    public static int Width = 10;
    public static int Weight = 12;
    public static string Name = "Got It";

    public override string ToString()
    {
        string result = string.Empty;
        Type type = typeof(ReflectionTest); 
        FieldInfo[] fields = type.GetFields();
        foreach (var field in fields)
        {
            string name = field.Name; 
            object temp = field.GetValue(null);
            result += "Name:" + name + ":" + temp.ToString() + System.Environment.NewLine;
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why not just override `ABC.ToString()` to return what you want?

Comment: @Sean, manually returning "desired properties" does not scale well.

Comment: @AndreiV - who said anything about retaining them?

Comment: @AndreiV arguably reflection and concatanating strings every time doesn't either

Comment: @Sean, I'm confused then. He does say that he wants to overwrite the `ToString()` method. There are two possibilities: manually writing "key/value" pairs containing "property name/property value" or dynamically getting the properties and their values using reflection. Am I wrong? What did you have in mind?

Comment: @owen79, I can't say I disagree. There's a trade off between programmer laziness (let's call it scalability) and program execution time.

Answer (score 1):

```
public override string ToString()
{
    Dictionary<string, string> fieldValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    var fields = this.GetType().GetFields();

    foreach (var field in fields)
    {
        fieldValues[field.Name] = field.GetValue(this).ToString();
    }

    return string.Join(", ", fieldValues.Select(x => string.Format("{0}: {1}", x.Key, x.Value)));
}
```

Comment: FieldInfo will not give me the value , i can get it from from propertyInfo

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is what you mean;

```
public override ToString() 
{
    return string.Format("one: {1}{0}two: {2}", Environment.NewLine(), one, two);
}
```

Comment: I think he wants a general approach using reflection.

Answer (score 0):

You could either use a property to retrieve the string, or override `ToString()`, both are shown:

```
public class ABC
{
    private Int32 _one = 10;
    public Int32 One { get { return _one; } }
    private String _two = "123";
    public String Two { get { return _two; } }

    protected override ToString()
    {
        return _two;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think the problem is overriding `ToString`. I think the question is rather "How do I enumerate all fields of a class using reflection and then create a string from them`.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
public override string ToString() {
    string s = "";
    foreach(FieldInfo f in this.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)) {
        s += f.Name + "=" + f.GetValue(this).ToString() + "\r\n";
    }
    return s;
}
```

`BindingFlags.Public` reflects only public members. If you want private member too, use also the `BindingFlags.Private` flag.
You may use the `this.GetType().GetFields()` at object initialization, to call it only once.

This works for framework 2 also.
Change it to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

So, here it is:

```
public class ABC
    {
        public int one;
        public string two;
        public int three;

        public override string ToString()
        {
            string names = String.Empty;
            System.Reflection.FieldInfo[] infos = this.GetType().GetFields();

            foreach (System.Reflection.MemberInfo inf in infos)
            {
                if (names == String.Empty)
                {
                    names = inf.Name;
                }
                else
                {
                    names += ';' + inf.Name;
                }
            }

            return names;
        }
    }
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Reflection, you can use any of the following two approaches:

1: Here you can serialize your class object to a JSON object which would be more readable:

```
    public override string ToString()
    {

        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ABC));
        string str;
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            serializer.WriteObject(stream, this);
            stream.Position = 0;
            using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
            {

                str = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }

        return str;
}
```

2: Here you can serialize your class object to XML which can be utilize some where else:

```
    public override string ToString()
    {

        XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ABC));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        var xtw = XmlTextWriter.Create(sb);
        s.Serialize
            (xtw, this);

        return sb.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally Get solution to my problem :)

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyClass mC= new MyClass();
        string result = mC.ToString();
    }
}

class MyClass
{
    string someValue = "One";
    int someValue1 = -1;
    bool someValue2 = false;
    float someValue3 = 2.2f;

    public string SomeValue
    {
        get{ return this.someValue;}
    }

    public int SomeValue1
    {
        get { return this.someValue1; }
    }

    public bool SomeValue2
    {
        get { return this.someValue2; }
    }

    public float SomeValue3
    {
        get { return this.someValue3; }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        string result = string.Empty;
        Type type = this.GetType();
        PropertyInfo [] pInfo = type.GetProperties();

        for (int i = 0; i <= pInfo.Length-1; i++)
        {
            Type internalType = this.GetType();
            PropertyInfo pInfoObject = internalType.GetProperty(pInfo[i].Name);
            object value = pInfoObject.GetValue(this,null);
            result += pInfo[i].Name + " : " + value.ToString() + System.Environment.NewLine;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is an other solution if we use static fields and fieldsInfo:**

```
    class ReflectionTest
{
    public static int Height = 2;
    public static int Width = 10;
    public static int Weight = 12;
    public static string Name = "Got It";

    public override string ToString()
    {
        string result = string.Empty;
        Type type = typeof(ReflectionTest); 
        FieldInfo[] fields = type.GetFields();
        foreach (var field in fields)
        {
            string name = field.Name; 
            object temp = field.GetValue(null);
            result += "Name:" + name + ":" + temp.ToString() + System.Environment.NewLine;
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```